# How to change Winamp's default Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, winamp

I want to make music play/pause pressing <kbd>space</kbd> (like it does in VLC).

How can I change this?

**Edit:** I am aware of global hotkey option, but i dont want it to be global, thus, i dont want to pause/unpause every time i press space while writing a message... :D

Comment: Use VLC ... :D dont bother it. although vlc is quite better than winamp.

Answer (score 5):

The Winamp Global hotkeys are designed to be global,
so as to continue working even while Winamp is minimized to the background.
This is by design and cannot be changed - all I can offer is a workaround.

Here is my workaround :

1. Disable in Preferences all the Global hotkeys that you do not need,
   only leaving the ones you intend to use.
2. Assign these Global hotkeys to unlikely key combinations that will never be used for anything else.
   For example assigning <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to play/pause.
3. Use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a script that, only when Winamp has the focus,
   maps the hotkeys you really want to use to these defined shortcuts.
   For example, map <kbd>Space</kbd> to the play/pause shortcut of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: That is a complex, but doable way I think.... useful resource: https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Winamp.htm

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> -> Preferences -> General Preferences -> Global hotkeys, there should have checkbox to enable editing the key combinations.

Choose action and at the "hotkey" press the <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: i dont want it to be global key... i just want it to work when winamp is focused.

Comment: They are builded like that, no direct way to override them. There are some plugins, which I haven`t tested.

Comment: This answer does not accomplish the question requeriments. I'm in the same issue, not wanting to set a GLOBAL hotkey.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to have the spacebar act as the "pause" button of WinAmp by modifying the accelerator tables in the executable with Resource Hacker (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). For instance, I edited the accelerator with ID 40046 (which was `VK_C`, corresponding to the current shortcut for the Pause button) in the three accelerator tables containing it (1371, 1372, 1373), by replacing it with `VK_SPACE` (then you have to click the *Compile script* button on the top).

[image: Editing VK_C to have VK_SPACE]

In one of the accelerator tables (1372) there is already a VK_SPACE accelerator. I just removed it (as leaving it there was preventing the spacebar to act as Pause/Unpause if the playlist window was focused). Not sure what the space was doing before in the playlist.

All the other default keyboard shortcuts of Winamp could be changed the same way.

Note that you will probably not be able to edit Winamp.exe in-place in its installation folder (except if running Resource Hacker with elevated privileges), so the easiest is to make a copy somewhere else and copy it back. Make sure anyway to keep a copy of the original executable, in case something goes wrong.